# Is this char array stored on the stack?

Tags: c++, c

In the following:

```
void frequentlyCalledFunction()
{
    char str[] = "Hello this is a really long string, imagine it's even longer"; // STORED ON STACK 

    printf("%s", str);
}

int main()
{
 
    frequentlyCalledFunction();
}
```

The string literal would have to be kept in the .data segment of the program, and since that char array is on the stack (I'm pretty sure), the program would have to copy that string from the .data segment to the stack every time the function is called, right?

Comment: Do note that as far as C++ is concerned there is no stack or heap (accept for the data structures).  There is just different storage durations for objects.  How this actually gets implemented will be implementation defined.

Comment: Completely up to the compiler. If the compiler can validate that it is not modified, then why would it even need to copy it out of the .data segment. See the [`As If`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule.

Comment: You do know "C" and "C++" are different languages right? So in general on tag one of the two answers might differ (not in this case)

Comment: @NathanOliver, True, but it's BS. Do you go around telling people that C++ doesn't support recursion too? I doubt it. (Recursion requires a stack.)

Comment: If it were any other function you called, the answer would be "probably yes". But standard library functions are not like other functions. They are formally part of the implementation and it may assume additional things about them, and so do as Martin York says.

Comment: @ikegami While the go to is a stack and a heap, there is nothing stopping a C++ implementation from dynamically allocating all objects with automatic storage duration and then deleting them when the scope exits.  C++ doesn't care how the underlying storage works, just that it follows the lifetime semantics.

Comment: @ikegami: Recursion requires a stack in unbounded theoretical computers. It does not require a stack in bounded situations, and the C standard explicitly allows bounds. Special-purpose compilers for embedded systems may produce code with fixed allocations for each routine to be called, with limited support for separate instances for recursive calls.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I know what the spec says. It's like you didn't read what I said. Recursion requires a stack, and I seriously doubt you object whenever someone uses recursion. Am I'm wrong and you do object? If not, why is that? Is there a benefit to your comment you don't believe yourself? (These are rhetorical.)

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*Recursion requires a stack in unbounded theoretical computers.*", No, recursion requires a stack, period. There are more than one way this stack could be implemented, but you need a stack for the variables to be present/restored after a recursive call returns.

Comment: @ikegami: ”No, recursion requires a stack, period”: No, it does not. A program with the call chain `main` ➝ `foo` ➝ `bar` does not require a stack, since each routine can be provided with its own statically allocated memory, and a program the compiler can determine has the call chain `main` ➝ `foo` ➝ `foo` has equivalent behavior to `main` ➝ `foo` ➝ `bar` with `bar` made to be a copy of `foo`, so it also can be implemented by providing `main`, the first instance of `foo`, and the second instance of `foo` with their own statically allocated memory.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Again, there are many ways to implement the stack. That is indeed one of them. But it's needed nonetheless.

Comment: @ikegami: No, that is a way to implement recursion without a hardware stack, which is the stack OP is asking about.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, No moving the goal post. Noone said anything about a hardware stack. (What does that even mean? Machines that don't have a dedicated `push` and `pop` instruction can't have a stack?)

Comment: @ikegami: Re “What does that even mean?”: It is the memory region set up by the program loader for the main program stack, plus the ABI that specifies how it is used, plus various mechanisms for managing it, which may include push and pop instructions, preferred registers for call and return instructions. Programs can have many stacks (they are easily implemented), but when somebody refers to “the stack,” not “a stack,” in the general context of an ordinary program, they are referring to this stack. That is what OP asked about, the standard program stack for their system, not any other stack.

Comment: The `str` variable is only used in the `printf` statement, so it can be optimized out.  The compiler can substitute the address of the text literal in the `printf` statement, example: `printf("%s", 0x4056789);`  The text literal should be placed into a read-only segment.  Some compilers may place the data into the executable.  In general, the *stack* should be treated as precious and limited in size compared to the other memory areas.  Usually, the read-only segments would be larger than the stack area.

Comment: Try replacing `printf` with `fwrite` or `puts`.  The `printf` is overkill for text that has no format specifiers.  The `puts` is faster than `printf`, but slower than `fwrite`, because `puts` is scanning for a termination character.  The `fwrite` is faster since it knows the length of the string, so it is streaming data to the console port (no scanning, no formatting).

Comment: _"The string literal would have to be kept in the .data segment of the program"_ — Note that the string literal can be also put into the text (code) segment, and copied to the stack if necessary. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/nYnjK6df9.

Comment: @NathanOliver it's not even implementation-defined (which means the implementation must document the behviour) . Just an implementation detail

Comment: @Eric Potpischil, Re "*in the general context of an ordinary program, they are referring to this stack.*",  That's absolutely false. They're not referring to any specific implementation. Threads have a stack. Perl programs have a stack. Python programs have a stack. But you claim they don't, and that's ludicrous.  Yes, it must be able to save the current state as you described, but the other qualifications don't apply.

Comment: @ikegami: Fine, in a multithreaded program, they are referring to the stack of a thread. OP’s question does not involve multithreading and is about the main stack of a program.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Re "*they are referring to the stack of a thread.*", So then you agree that the stack doesn't need to be a hardware stack (as you defined it)? So we're back to where I started: One is being a major hypocrite if one decries the existence of the stack in C while accepting the use of recursion. One is necessary for the other.

Comment: @ikegami: The OP is asking about the main stack for their program. The fact it is not implemented so directly in hardware for some Perl or Python implementations is irrelevant. The fact that C and C++ have stack-like semantics is not relevant, because OP appears to be asking about “the stack” in contrast to the data segment they explicitly mention. They did not ask about the C or C++ abstractions of automatically allocated memory. Noting that the automatically allocated memory is stack-like does not mean that is the stack they were asking about.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Re "*The fact it is not implemented so directly in hardware for some Perl or Python implementations is irrelevant*", EXACTLY! That's what I've been saying the start, but you kept insisting otherwise!

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Re "*The fact that C and C++ have stack-like semantics is not relevant*", I never said otherwise. I didn't say anything about "stack-like" at all. I said it's hypocritical to mention C has no stack while also accepting that C has recursion, because the latter requires the former.

Comment: @ikegami AFAIK, threads have their own stacks, but these are "hardware" stacks as well. In the sense that each thread has its own stack pointer and use CPU instructions to manipulate its stack.

Comment: @Daniel Langr, Not by the definition Eric Postpischil gave. (They aren't created by the loader.) And his def of a hardware stack is VERY different than yours. According to Eric, everybody knows the OP is talking about a "hardware stack", whatever that is. But considering the definitions you and Eric gave couldn't possibly be any more different, that claim is clearly false. "Hardware stack" is a loose term with no accepted definition. And it speaks to implementation which is completely irrelevant here. We're talking about the *call stack* (Eric's "the stack"), regardless of implementation

Answer (score 6):

> The string literal would have to be kept in the .data segment of the program,

The existence of a .data segment, or of segments at all, and the details of what might or might not reside in one are characteristics of the operating environment, not of C or C++.  What the languages say is that the string literal has *static storage duration*, which means that it exists and keeps its last-stored value (which for a string literal is also its initial value) for the entire run of the program.

> and since that char array is on the stack (I'm pretty sure),

The existence of a stack (in the sense you mean) is a characteristic of the operating environment, not of C or C++.  What the languages say is that the array is a different object than the literal, and that the array has *automatic storage duration*, which means that it exists and maintains its last -stored value from the point where control reaches its declaration until the termination of the innermost containing block.

> the program would have to copy that string from the .data segment to the stack every time the function is called, right?

According to the semantics of the abstract machines on which C and C++ language semantics are defined, yes, the contents of the string literal are copied into the array every time the function is called.

HOWEVER, what actually happens is an altogether different question.  C and C++ allow for implementations to behave in any way whatever, so long as they produce externally visible behavior that matches the externally visible behavior required of the abstract machines.  This is the playground of compiler optimizations, and modern compilers can be pretty aggressive about it.

In your particular example, I would expect most compilers to optimize out the local array altogether when optimizations were enabled, but you could probably force the copy you're asking about by modifying some of the elements of the local array in a manner that the compiler cannot pre-compute at compile time.

Comment: OT: It's kind of interesting that in this example, the string is still copied from the code segment to the stack, even if it can't be modified (without some const cast): https://godbolt.org/z/z35ebqczE. But maybe I'm missing some case here.

Comment: @DanielLangr, I don't find that particularly surprising.  Although I didn't consider it in this answer, the fact that the function in that example passes a pointer into the array to an external function is a pretty good reason for the compiler not to optimize the array out.  It might be different if the definition of function `g()` were available to be inlined.

Answer (score 1):

The `str[]` object is only 'on the stack' in the sense that accessing its data would only be defined behavior within the scope of the function after its declaration.

However, there is no deterministic answer as to how the program populates `str[]` at the call of the function, or if it does at all. The characters might be converted to several 8-byte/4-byte/2-byte objects and copied to the string. The data could thus be embedded in the assembly for the function itself and copied with `movabs` instructions. (This would be at the assembly level and thus not violate any strict aliasing rules). Or there might be a string in the `.data` section, that is either copied to `str[]` or is simply used in place of `str[]` and `str[]` is optimized away. Any of these differences would not affect the observable behavior of the program by any means defined by the Standard, and thus there is no deterministic answer as to which one happens as per the C/C++ Standard.

Any test that **could** produce different results based on how `str[]` is allocated would necessarily involve behavior that is not defined by the Standard. For example, you could **try to** determine if `str[]` is actually allocated on the stack by returning a reference to it and calling other functions that would overwrite any stack memory and then see if it still has the original contents, but at that point you had already invoked undefined behavior and your results are non-deterministic anyway.

Comment: Re the edit: the array goes out of scope and life when the function returns, so a reference to it would be invalid: but it might disrupt the optimatisation.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hence, undefined behavior. Anything could happen.

Comment: So why suggest it? I may be be wrong, but I thought you added the UB remark in the editing grace period.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was making the point that any attempt made to determine the way `str[]` is stored would not be deterministic because it would rely on the behavior of UB.

Comment: It is unlikely to be placed on the stack.  According to the C standard, `6.4.5/6`, string literals have static duration.  At the end of the day, the compiler can choose where to store it.

Comment: @David Jones, The question isn't about the string literal but `str`, into which a copy of the string literal is purportedly made. (`char str[] = "...";` isn't the same as `char *str = "...";`)

Comment: Ah yes, in that case `char s[] = "abc"` is identical to `char s[] = { ’a’, ’b’, ’c’, ’\0’ }`

Comment: @ikegami the observable behaviour is the same in both cases, for this particular program

Comment: @M.M I know. I was telling David Jones that their comment was irrelevant, and what you just said doesn't change that. The fact that the the static literal can be stored anywhere and anyhow says nothing about `str`.